# Xcode suddenly found an error while compiling

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I do not understand, why Xcode started failing. It worked correctly, but now — not.
Why? Any ideas?

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5F0F3220-FB4F-4AF1-BC9E-6EF464E24448/signum.app/signum
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5F0F3220-FB4F-4AF1-BC9E-6EF464E24448/signum.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5F0F3220-FB4F-4AF1-BC9E-6EF464E24448/signum.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

(lldb)
```

[image: fail1 image]

[image: fail2 image]

Comment: Explain your issue in words, not with a video

Comment: Don’t post links to video. Describe in words. Paste the error message into your question.

Comment: Not as a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed, Instead of telling OP to accept my answer let the choice to OP for upVote and Accept the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just clean the project :

```
shift+cmd+k
```

Comment: It's better to post this as comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Previously commented on the question and this is the answer. Then post as an answer.  What's the wrong with this @Pankil.